# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Jasper Reports Server

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jasperserver

I have installed MySQL's JDBC driver both by MySQL installer and manually downloading from MySQL's web site but still I get this error in JasperReports Server 6.2.0:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
```

How can I add the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v561/managing-jdbc-drivers

Comment: Note the mariadb driver should already be installed..

Comment: @PetterFriberg, can you post the link as an answer.

Comment: I prefer your answer, include the link in answer... and then remember to check accepted... (maybe you need to wait some days...)

Answer (score 1):

There ( http://www.example.com:8080/jasperserver ) was database connection. I had to edit it. It asked me to upload the JDBC.

[image: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v561/managing-jdbc-drivers ([Petter Friberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177003/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-jasper-reports-server?noredirect=1#comment58072013_35177003))

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the driver in tomcat lib folder "$CATALINA_HOME/lib".